# How can I prove that two lines intersect at a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, quadrilateral

There is a triangle $ABC$. Its inscribed circle touches the sides $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ in points $N$, $K$ and $M$ respectively. The lines $MN$ and $MK$ intersect the exterior angle $B$ bisector in points $R$ and $S$. How can I prove that the lines $RK$ and $SN$ intersect at the circle?

[image: Figure]

Comment: This can be done using lines and circle equation and finally prove that the lines you mention intersect with circle. This is not pure geometry and not sure if you are looking for this kind of analytic solution.

Comment: Maybe that is still a good idea which can lead to another solution. Could you post your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\measuredangle SBK=\measuredangle RBN=\measuredangle NMK=90^{\circ}-\frac{\beta}{2},$$
we see that quadrilaterals $RBKM$ and $MNBS$ are cyclics.

Thus, $$180^{\circ}-\measuredangle NIK=\measuredangle SRI+\measuredangle RSI=\measuredangle BMK+\measuredangle BMN=\measuredangle NMK,$$
which says that $MNIK$ is cyclic and we are done!

Comment: How can I prove that the angles RBN and NMK are equal?

Comment: @student28 $\measuredangle MNK=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle NMA-\measuredangle KMC=180^{\circ}-\left(90^{\circ}-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)-\left(90^{\circ}-\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)=\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\gamma}{2}=90^{\circ}-\frac{\beta}{2}=\measuredangle RBN$.

Comment: At the beginning it should be $\measuredangle NMK$.